# Return all Workflows in a Site Collection using REST API

Tags: workflow, rest

Using REST API, how do you list all the Workflows in a SharePoint 2013 Site Collection?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it lists all workflows for subsites, and I don't think it lists 2010 type workflows, only 2013 type workflows, but a place to start would be:

```
https://server/sites/rootweb/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionService.Current/EnumerateSubscriptions
```

That does require a `POST` and a valid form digest value, which you can either get off a page, or from `/_api/contextinfo` (which also requires a `POST`, but doesn't need the form digest).

If it doesn't list workflows for subsites, you could always just work down the tree by getting all subsites

```
https://server/sites/rootweb/_api/web/webs
```

and then query each of those for their workflows.